# Setting path in Solaris Sparc

Tags: path, solaris

I have one python command file, i want to set it as a PATH in Solaris Sparc so that i can easily use my command from anywhere. For example the file name is abc.py and it contains abc --version to display version of file abc. So, after opening terminal i should only give command abc --version and it should display version of abc.

Comment: Add it as an alias to your `.bashrc`

Comment: added an alias but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The architecture (SPARC) has nothing to do with the PATH which is more a shell thing but you do not tell what shell you are using.

Anyway, if you use a bourne style shell, i.e. not `csh/tcsh`, and you don't mind this to affect every user account on that host, you might add the wanted path to the PATH setting in the file `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 0):

When abc.py is located in your homedir, you can start it with `~/abc.py`.
You need to call the file abc.py with `abc.py`, not `abc` (and have a shebang line which instructs the shell where it can find python).
When you want to start the file with ./abc, you can rename the file to abc (the shebang will tell it is python, not the `.py`), or introduce an alias:

```
alias abc="~/abc.py"
```

Using an alias can be an alternative for adding a shebang line:

```
alias abc="/usr/bin/python abc.py"
```

When you do not want to use an alias you can make a bin dir and put abc there.
I will add the shebang for you:

```
mkdir ~/bin
echo "#!/usr/bin/python" > ~/bin/abc
cat abc.py >> ~/bin/abc
chmod +x ~/bin/abc
mv abc.py bin/abc.py.old
```

Now change your login PATH with `PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/bin` in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`, and login again (or `source` the login script).